# Lightning - Notes

Tags: lightning, notes

From the lightning experience trailhead I read that it is possible to associate one note to multiple records

> **"You can even relate a note to multiple records"**

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/lex_migration_introduction/lex_migration_introduction_whatis

Can someone tell me how this is possible ?

A Note can be associated to one record only right ?

From the workbench I can see that there can only be one parent as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, we can create notes and associate it to multiple records (e.g. Contacts, Opportunity as in picture) like this which is generally available from Winter'16 release:

Steps:

> 1. Create Note and associate to multiple records. We can share this to people or user.

[image: Adding notes to multiple objects]

> 2. This saved notes can be accessible from Files menu.

[image: Notes under files tab]

> 3. To retrieve the notes from workbench, use the SOQL query on `ContentDocument`

[image: Notes at ContentDocument]

> 4. Difference between Notes vs Old Note-Taking tool

[image: Notes vs Old Note-Taking tool]

For more information, Refer [Adding Notes to Records](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/project/quicklook-lightning-experience/ql-lex-5) Trailhead

Answer (score 5):

The `Note` object that has been around for many years is replaced by the `ContentNote` object when [enhanced notes are enabled](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=notes_admin_setup.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

On the underlying SObjects involved, see this [ContentNote Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_contentnote.htm?search_text=ContentDocumentLink%20erd) documentation page that includes this ERD:

[image: ERD]

The many-to-many relationship is achieved through the `ContentDocumentLink` object.

Comment: So in reality a copy of the note is created (the intersection table). It is not really a pure sharing of a single note to multiple records.
Eg : N1 note is associated to O1 opportunity and A1 account. So internally N1x, N1y records (each ContentDocumentLink object) will be created for that "share".
Am I right ?

Comment: @AaronWilfred The ContentDocumentLink is an association object that only connects the note with another object. So the one note can be related to multiple objects.